# Are there any APIs that list Envelope IDs as a Signer?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm looking for an API call that would effectively allow a Signer account to poll for Envelope IDs. Ideally I would like to get the envelopes id's of documents that fall under the "Action Needed" criteria.

I have looked into using the listStatusChanges GET Request, but it only returns envelope ID's that have been sent from other Docusign accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example. For you to use this, you would need to replace your account and user Ids

```
GET <serverURI>/restapi/v2.1/accounts/ae232f1f-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-626847fad8bb/envelopes?from_date=2020-01-26T08:00:00.000Z&to_date=2020-03-29T06:59:58.000Z&user_id=ee76c29e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-a0f95cd8e225&start_position=0&count=39&order=desc&order_by=last_modified&folder_ids=awaiting_my_signature&folder_types=normal,inbox,sentitems&include=recipients,powerform,folders&include_purge_information=true&query_budget=3
```

This is probably more than you need, but that's how the web app does it.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: do you mind marking this question as answered Masato?